# Possible to use AMD gDEBugger 6.0 only for OpenCL CPU Kernel debugging? NVIDIA GPU seems to hold this off

Tags: windows, debugging, opencl, nvidia

is there a way to make AMD gDEBugger 6 debug at least OpenCL CPU Kernels even though a dedicated NVIDIA GPU is installed?

When I start the gDEBugger, I get a warning: *You do not have an AMD GPU installed. Kernel debugging will be disabled.*

Well, I just want to debug CPU kernels...

My development environment:

NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4 --> for GPU kernel creation

AMD APP SDK --> for CPU kernel creation

OS: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

My OpenCL program itself runs fine, both platforms are found without any changes in my VC project properties and the kernel can be executed on my CPU as well as on my GPU.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Debugging OpenCL Kernel on CPU is not possible or not available with AMD gDEBugger 6.0 or even 6.1 does not have this feature.